# Property of series of independent random variables that have same distribution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3 ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables that have same distribution with bounded variance.
Let $S_n$ be random variable that is a sum of first $n$ of $X_i$.

I need to prove that $lim\; \mathbb{P}(S_n \le b)$  exists and has only $0, 1, 0.5$ as possible values.

Because of $0-1$ Kolmogorov's law this series either converge or not.
If $\mathbb{E}X_i > 0$ then $\mathbb{E}S_n = n\mathbb{E}X_1 \to \infty$ and I guess(Not sure how to prove it precisely) this is the case of $0$ for every $b$. And if $\mathbb{E}X_1<0$ this should be case of $1$ for every b.

Now going to case of $\mathbb{E}X_i = 0$ we can see that $\mathbb{E}S_n = 0$ too. Now the series converges to $0$ but I don't understand how to get this $0.5$ for $b = 0$ in case of my intuition not being wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By SLLN's $\frac {S_n} n \to m$ a.s., hence also in probability,  where $m$ is the mean.

Case 1)

$m>0$

Take $\epsilon \in ( 0, m)$ and note that $P(S_n \leq b)\leq P(|\frac {S_n} n-m| >\epsilon) \to 0$.

Case 2)

$m <0$.

Take $0<\epsilon <-m$ and note that $P(S_n > b)\leq  P(|\frac {S_n} n-m| >\epsilon) \to 0$. Hence $P(S_n \leq b) \to 1$.

Case 3)

$m=0$.

Here $P(S_n \leq b)= P(\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n} \leq \frac b {\sqrt n}) \to \Phi(0)=\frac 1 2$ (by CLT) where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function .